# I want to verify the existence of a file in a linux container from linux virtual machine

Tags: containers, lxc

I am on my virtual machine and I must find a way to connect to the container and verify if there is a specific file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled SSH in your container, then you should be able to login to it from anywhere (even from the VM).

```
ssh usernae@lxc-hostname
```

Once logged in you can search for the file. There are various tools, but I like to use the **locate** command line tool.

```
locate <filename>
```

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Without SSH you can view the files and directory of the LXC containers; For this we need to find the pid (process identifier) of the container.

```
   $>lxc-info -pHn <container-name-C1>
```

The above command will return you the pid number of the container launched by name C1

Now go to /proc/'{pid}'/root/; From this place you can view all the files of the lxc container by name C1; The beauty of LXC :)